# Show that $\gamma$ is homomorphism. (Reduction Modulo n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $\gamma$  be the natural map of $\mathbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z_n$, given by  $\gamma(m)=r$ where $r$ is the remainder given by the Division Algorithm when $m$ is divided by $n$, show that $ \gamma$ is a homomorphism.

Solution:
As I solve this problem, I show that 
$$\gamma(s+t)=\gamma(s)+\gamma(t),$$ for $s,t \in\mathbb{Z}$.
Using the Division algorithm,
$$s=q_1n+r_1$$ and $$t=q_2n+r_2,$$ where $0\le r_i\lt n$, for $ i=1,2$.
If $ r_1+r_2=q_3n+r_3$, for $0\leq r_3\lt n$.
Adding $s$ and $t$, I got
$$s+t=(q_1+q_2+q_3)n+r_3.$$
Here, I just don't know what is next. I'm having trouble in making conclusion in the last line of my solution. Please help me.

Comment: First of all, you want to show that it is an homomorphism of what? Abelian groups? Commutative rings? $\mathbb{Z}$-Modules?

Comment: A homomorphism in $\mathbb Z$-Modules Sir

Comment: Ok, I wrote the one for groups. I will add the part for modules.

Comment: Please stop calling me "sir" :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove that it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-[module homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_homomorphism), we have to first prove that it is a homomoprhism of groups, and second that it respects the $\mathbb{Z}$-module operation, i.e. $\gamma(\alpha t)=\alpha\gamma(t)$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$. I would do it like the following.

First of all, recall that $$\mathbb{Z}_n=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}=\{x+n\mathbb{Z}\mid x\in\mathbb{Z}\},$$ i.e. the group of lateral classes of $n\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, where the sum is defined in the natural way as
$$(a+n\mathbb{Z})+(b+n\mathbb{Z})=a+b+n\mathbb{Z}.$$

In your case, then,
$$\gamma(s)=s+n\mathbb{Z}, \quad \gamma(t)=t+n\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$\gamma(s+t)=s+t+n\mathbb{Z}.$$

By plugging these definitions in the definition of the operation above, we obtain the first part of the statement, i.e. it is a groups homomorphism.

For the second part, we have to recall the definition of the (natural) action of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_n$, i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z_n}&\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n\\
(\alpha, s+n\mathbb{Z})&\longmapsto \alpha(s+n\mathbb{Z})=(\alpha s)+n\mathbb{Z}
\end{aligned}
$$

For this and from the definition of $\gamma$, then,
$$\alpha \gamma(s)=\alpha(s+n\mathbb{Z})=(\alpha s)+n\mathbb{Z}=\gamma(\alpha s).$$

And so also the second condition is verified.

Answer (score 0):

$\gamma(st)=\gamma(s+...+s)=\gamma(s)+...+\gamma(s)$, where sums have $t$ summands. Since the order of the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is $n$, we can leave only $r_2$ summands in the last sum. So, $\gamma(st)=r_2\gamma(s)=\gamma(t)\gamma(s)$. For $t<0$ we note $\gamma(0-s)+\gamma(s)=\gamma(0)=\{obviously\}=0$ and so $\gamma(-s)=-\gamma(s)$

Comment: What if $t$ is negative?

Comment: I just wanted to use the author's part of the solution, sir:)